# django related field filter with range

Tags: python, django

I tried to filter the range of keyword_id in the book table. However, the following error continues to occur. How can I filter the range of keyword_id?

here is my code

```
UserBook.objects.prefetch_related('book').filter(book__keyword_id__range=(2,7)).values(
'book_id').annotate(count=Count('book_id')).order_by('-count')
```

it is error

```
raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: range
```

here is models.py

```
class UserBook(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book        = models.ForeignKey('book.Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    page        = models.IntegerField()
    time        = models.IntegerField()
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta :
        db_table = 'user_books'

class Book(models.Model):
    title             = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    subtitle          = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)
    image_url         = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    company           = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    author            = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    about_author      = models.TextField(null=True)
    contents          = models.TextField(default='')
    company_review    = models.TextField(null=True)
    page              = models.IntegerField(default='')
    publication_date  = models.DateField()
    description       = models.TextField(null=True)
    category          = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    keyword           = models.ForeignKey(Keyword, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    reviews           = models.ManyToManyField('user.User', through='Review')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'books'
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
book__keyword_id__range(2,7)
```

with:

```
book__keyword_id__range=(2,7) # needs to be "=" sign.
```

doc is [here about range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#range)

Comment: if this does not solve your problem, please put your models in your question.

Comment: I tried as you said, but it didn't solve the problem. I uploaded models.py in the body. I would appreciate it if you check.

Comment: I solved this problem. I used gte, not range. Thanks for the answer.